# Selenium xpath - Unable to find the xpath

Tags: selenium

I need to get the text "No results found, click tab to use entered text" from below html.

```html
<div id="boundlist-1520-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;">
<ul></ul>
No results found, click tab to use entered text
</div>
```

When I tried with div id, its throwing the error.

Can anyone help me to get the xpath of this.

Many Thanks.

Regards,
Sudha Banakar

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Add the xpath you are using

Comment: Which Selenium client are you using Java/Python/C# ?

Comment: id seems dynamic, try with classname `x-boundlist-list-ct`

Answer (score 0):

I guess Your id is changed dynamically so that you need to identify it by start with or contains method.Following XPath will work for you

`"//div[starts-with(@id,'boundlist-')]`

You can verify XPath by pasting it on your google chrome console

```
$x("//div[starts-with(@id,'boundlist-')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath is :-
    //ul[contains(text(),'No results found, click tab to use entered text')]

or best is 
    //*[contains(text(),'No results found, click tab to use entered text')]

Answer (score -1):

If text displayed is not getting changed then you can use below xpath

```
//div[text()='No results found, click tab to use entered text']
```